# dll injection war3

Tags: c++, dll, assembly, code-injection

I have ths code:

```
    __asm
    {
     PUSHAD
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[hStorm_LOBBYPTR]
     TEST       EAX, EAX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0xC464]
     TEST       ECX, ECX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x170+0xB0]
     TEST       EAX, EAX
     JE         nick_false
     MOV        EDX, i
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+EDX*4]
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x1A0]
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0x1E4]
     MOV        EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ECX+0x1E4]
     MOV        ECX, DWORD PTR DS:[EAX+0x1E8]
     MOV        tempdw, ECX
     POPAD
     JMP        nick_true

nick_false:
     XOR        EAX, EAX
     MOV        tempdw, EAX
     POPAD
    }

nick_true:
        /* do check if tempdw is NULL and then proceed with your stuff */
```

1. How can I wrap it into DLL (Visual Studio C++ 2008)?
2. After that, I need to inject the DLL into some process and then retrieve tempdw, how can I do that?

Comment: Did you get this code from somewhere else because if you were able to write this then doing what you ask would be trivial.... just saying

Comment: Are you trying to hack a game? ;)

Comment: yes, i got this code from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to warp that in a normal C func, however, judging by the labels, it won't be a naked func:

```
void MyHook()
{
    __asm
   {
     //asm here
   }

nick_true:
    //the other stuff
}
```

this then needs to be put into a basic dll project that writes the needed hooks using `WriteProcessMemory` (nothing more than that can be given as there isn't enough info).
To inject it, you can use [RemoteDll](http://securityxploded.com/remotedll.php) or edit the launcher from [w3l](http://w3l.info.tm/)